# Calling a Variable from a Struct Instance Syntax Issue C++

Tags: c++, syntax, struct, instance

As much as I hate to ask a question about what may be a simple syntax issue I'm not aware of, the assignment deadline looms and I'm completely stumped, with none of the information I've looked up seeming to be of use. I have a struct in a header file:

```
struct roomStruct
{
    // The room the player is currently in, and its interactive objects.
    string roomName;
    string size;
    int exits[dirnum];
    bool rustyKeyIn;
    bool goldKeyIn;
    bool copperKeyIn;
    bool rustyDoorIn;
    bool goldDoorIn;
    bool copperDoorIn;
    bool torchIn;
    bool toyIn;
    bool leverIn;
    bool brokenDoorIn;
    bool oldCheeseIn;
    bool toyBoxIn;
    bool skeletonIn;
    bool ghostIn;
};
```

And an instance of the struct like this (with more for each gen_rooms number, in the same format):

```
enum gen_dirs {north, east, south, west};
enum gen_rooms {entrance, bathroom, livingroom, diningroom, abedroom, cupboard, kitchen, cbedroom};

void genRooms(roomStruct *rms)
{
    // Generating the rooms of the house, and what items they contain
    rms[entrance].roomName.assign("the entrance hallway");
    rms[entrance].size.assign("small");
    rms[entrance].exits[north] = noexit;
    rms[entrance].exits[east] = noexit;
    rms[entrance].exits[south] = livingroom;
    rms[entrance].exits[west] = noexit;
    rms[entrance].rustyKeyIn = false;
    rms[entrance].goldKeyIn = false;
    rms[entrance].copperKeyIn = true;
    rms[entrance].rustyDoorIn = false;
    rms[entrance].goldDoorIn = false;
    rms[entrance].copperDoorIn = false;
    rms[entrance].torchIn = false;
    rms[entrance].toyIn = false;
    rms[entrance].leverIn = false;
    rms[entrance].brokenDoorIn = false;
    rms[entrance].oldCheeseIn = false;
    rms[entrance].toyBoxIn = false;
    rms[entrance].skeletonIn = false;
    rms[entrance].ghostIn = false;
```

I then attempt to call the roomName variable from the above instance, but I have no idea how to do so. I am aware this is an ugly input method for a text adventure, but that isn't the current issue.

```
int main()
{
    string verb;
    string noun;

    roomStruct rooms[roomnum];
    genRooms(rooms);

    int currentRoom = entrance;

    cout << "Welcome to GHOST HOUSE!!!" << endl << endl << "Please enter commands in the format 'verb -> enter -> noun -> enter' in all lower case." << endl << endl;

    // All commands will be in the format 'verb, noun', with the noun not being required for all commands. Currently, lower case is required.
    cout << "You are in the " << roomStruct.roomName << "." << endl;
    cout << "What do you want to do?" << endl;
    cin >> verb >> noun;
```

So what I am asking is what I need to replace roomStruct.roomName with. Thank you in advance, and again, sorry for such ugly coding.

Comment: @Triiby>> Are you storing "rms" any where? If not then how can you access it from main function?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, but the instance (the one with rms) is in the .cpp file, not the header, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
int main(){
string verb;
string noun;
roomStruct rooms[roomnum];
genRooms(rooms);
int currentRoom = entrance;
cout << "Welcome to GHOST HOUSE!!!" << endl << endl << "Please enter commands in the format 'verb -> enter -> noun -> enter' in all lower case." << endl << endl;
// All commands will be in the format 'verb, noun', with the noun not being required for all commands. Currently, lower case is required.
cout << "You are in the " << rooms[currentRoom].roomName << "." << endl;
cout << "What do you want to do?" << endl;
cin >> verb >> noun;
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: It did, thanks :) Might be able to get this thing written in time after all!